# How to set the color to a switch in appcelerator?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-studio

I tried with On tint color, color, tint color to change the color of the switch. It isn't working either way.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: I've just recently build an app that has this feature and works fine, what is your code?

Comment: <Alloy>
    <Window title="Switch">
        <Label id="state" class="stateLabel" />
        <Switch  onTintColor="blue"  id="colorswitch" class="switchControl" onChange="switchChanged" />
    </Window>
</Alloy>

Comment: function switchChanged(value) {
 
 if(value){
  $.colorswitch.onTintColor= "#c91326";
  alert("hi");
 }
 else{
  
  $.colorswitch.onTintColor= "#000000";
  alert("hi1");
 }
}

Comment: @faizal please edit your question to include the code there ;) Easier to read!

Comment: sure I'll make sure next time around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android you can use this theme to set a track and thumb tint color:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="MyThemeActionbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- switch -->
        <item name="switchStyle">@style/newSwitchStyle</item>
    </style>


    <style name="newSwitchStyle" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton">
        <item name="track">@drawable/abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha</item>
        <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/abc_switch_thumb_material</item>
        <item name="switchTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Switch</item>
        <item name="android:background">?attr/controlBackground</item>
        <item name="showText">false</item>
        <item name="switchPadding">@dimen/abc_switch_padding</item>
        <item name="android:textOn">@string/abc_capital_on</item>
        <item name="android:textOff">@string/abc_capital_off</item>

        <!-- track and button -->
        <item name="trackTint">#00f</item>
        <item name="thumbTint">#f00</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

- Create a file `platform/android/res/values/mytheme.xml` with the content above
- apply the theme with e.g. 
  `var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({theme: "Theme.MyThemeActionbar",});`
  or
- set it globally in the tiapp.xml:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <application android:theme="@style/Theme.MyThemeActionbar"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

Check: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Themes for applying/adding a theme

Comment: should it be changed  in tiapp.xml file?

Comment: no, it is a theme: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Themes

Comment: when i add the files and run after compilation the folder whatever i added is getting deleted automatically

Comment: platform/android/res/values/mytheme.xml here platform/android/alloy_generated is alone left after compilation

Comment: use the platform folder inside the app/ folder.

Comment: thanks for replying ,                                 [ERROR] :  Failed to package application:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  /Users/macmini1/Documents/wardTruck/Ward_Truck_Mobile/wardtruckmobile/build/android/res/values/theme.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.MyThemeActionbar'.
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

Comment: i followed the above steps that you suggested by setting globally in the tiapp.xml file

Comment: i changed the tiapp.xml file it worked fine. What if i want to change it using the change event? how should i access this property?